# Rails: NoMethodError - undefined method 'save'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, controller

In my controller I have this:

```
def hours_create
  @hour = params[:hour].map { |hour_attrs| Hour.create(hour_attrs) }  
  if @hour.save
    redirect_to :back, notice: "hour created."
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The error is coming from `@hour.save`, but not sure what to replace it, because I need to redirect the page somehow when item is saved into my database?

Why is there this error?

Thanks

Comment: @Pavan sorry the error is `undefined method `save' for #<Array:0x007fc46857b820>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is happening because `map` returns an array, and you're attempting to call `save` on that. Arrays within Ruby do not have the method `save` defined, hence the error.

Why are you trying to `save` anyway? `create` will validate the record and save it to the database if it's valid. You might want to use `create!` instead and rescue the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` error that's thrown when that fails:

```
def hours_create
  begin
    params[:hour].each { |hour_attrs| Hour.create!(hour_attrs) }  
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :new
  else
    redirect_to :back, notice: "hour created."
  end
end
```

---

Why is this action called `hours_create`? This is a code smell imo. It sounds like it should be in a controller of its own called `Hours`, which itself has a `create` method.

Comment: Oh thank you for your awesome answer! Yeah, you're right. I should put that in Hours controller... I really appreciate this!